# Add PNG overlay to multi output HLS M3U8 with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been banging my head for 2 days now. I can currently output 3 `M3U8 "HLS"` outputs resized but now I need to add an overlay to each output. The overlay image would need to be resized as well. My take on this is that the image should be applied to the source and then the 3 outputs can be generated. I have read that `-vf` cannot be used since there are 2 inputs. Here is what I am currently using which works.

> How could I add an image overlay?

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i input.mov^
 -vf scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease  -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 72 -keyint_min 72 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod  -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k -hls_flags single_file^
 360p.m3u8  
 -vf scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 72 -keyint_min 72 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 2800k -maxrate 2996k -bufsize 4200k -b:a 128k -hls_flags single_file 720p.m3u8^
 -vf scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 72 -keyint_min 72 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5350k -bufsize 7500k -b:a 192k -hls_flags single_file 1080p.m3u8
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mumble jumble of your code representing your second paragraph is poorly formatted, and hence your question is liable to downvotes. You should take action immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a filter_complex for the overlay filter, and then splitting the result into 3 and scaling each copy:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i input.mov -i image.png
       -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay,split=3[a][b][c];[a]scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[a];[b]scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[b];[c]scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[c]"
       -map "[a]" -map 0:a -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 72 -keyint_min 72 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k -hls_flags single_file 360p.m3u8
       -map "[b]" -map 0:a -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 72 -keyint_min 72 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 2800k -maxrate 2996k -bufsize 4200k -b:a 128k -hls_flags single_file 720p.m3u8
       -map "[c]" -map 0:a -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 72 -keyint_min 72 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5350k -bufsize 7500k -b:a 192k -hls_flags single_file 1080p.m3u8
```

(If your h264 encoder is x264, `b:v` has no effect when used with `crf`, but `maxrate` and `bufsize` do.)